# strip all comments from helm package

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, helm, kubernetes-helm

I have a lot of comments in my helm chart in my repository.
I want to deliver my helm chart to others without these comments.

I am hoping to be able to do this during my CI pipeline. I have a step in my pipeline which performs the `helm package` command. I am hoping to have this package completely stripped of comments (in the templates, values, etc)

I have not found a way to do this directly with helm.

Is there a simple solution to my problem?

I have already considered some ways to solve it but I feel like I am missing a simple solution here.
I know I can parse the values files and re write them using something like `yq` which will strip all comments. But that won't work for the template files as they are not valid yaml with the helm/go templating in them.

Comment: YAML comments or template comments - https://helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/templates/?

Answer (score 1):

If you running Linux-based agents/runners, then you may be able to integrate the following command into your CI pipeline:

```
find path/to/helmchart/directory/ -type f -exec sed -i '' '/^#/d' {} \;
```

In the above command we use the `find` command to list out all the files in the helm chart directory and then we use the `exec` switch to run a `sed` to delete the lines which begin with a `#` using the regex pattern `^#`.

The above command can be modified to include other regex patterns as defined by the use case.

Also note that only the comments which begin with a `#` would be removed from the files in the helm directory. Helm chart templates have comments in the form of `{{/* ... */}}`. These will not be stripped. But supplying another regex will be able to do this job too. I hope this helps.